# Importing CV2 does not work in Spyder but works in PyCharm

Tags: python, opencv, spyder

I have Anaconda 3 installed (Python 3.6.3) and I am working on a project that uses the CV2 package in python. Now I am relatively new to python but I have been using this package (via "import cv2" command) in PyCharm with no problems. However, today, I wanted to give Spyder a try. I started using the IDE and everything was working. But all of a sudden, Spyder kept giving me an error when I try to import cv2. I really did not change anything and I only was debugging the script. The error I am getting is as follows:

"""
In [1]: import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    import cv2

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
"""

I cannot figure out how this can be related to the IDE since PyCharm still can import it. Could anybody give me a hint please?

Comment: are you sure you're using the same environment in spyder as in pycharm?

Comment: Yes, it is the same env.

Answer (score 0):

As I know CV2 is python 2x related. When You use CV2 You need copy cv2.pyd file directly to python 2x site-packages.

Comment: The problem is everything was working and all of a sudden it stopped. Do you think something might have corrupted the file?

Comment: Install Anaconda with python 2x. Put cv2.pyd file from Your opencv to Anaconda2/Lib/site-packages/ . Change default python interpreter to python 2x in You editor(PyCharm, other) It is enough to use cv2 lib.